# CRTP: Determine derived class type in base class function to allow code reuse

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

Lets say I have a CRTP template class for matrices

```
template<class T, class Derived>
class MatrixBase{
private:
    //...

public:
    Derived some_function(const Derived &other){
          Derived& self = (Derived&)*this; // In my application I cant use static_cast.

          // Some calculations..., which will determine the below 
          // defined variables "some_number_of_rows" and "some_number_of_cols"

          // If Derived = DynamicMatrix<T>, then result should be declared as:
          DynamicMatrix<T> result(some_number_of_rows, some_number_of_cols);

          // while if Derived = StaticMatrix<T, Rows, Cols>, then result should be declared as:
          StaticMatrix<T, some_number_of_rows, some_number_of_cols> result;

          // Perform some more calculations...

          return result;
    }
};

template<class T>
class DynamicMatrix{
private:
     size_t n_rows, n_cols;
     T *data;
public:
     DynamicMatrix(const size_t n_rows, const size_t n_cols);
     // ...
};

template<class T, int Rows, int Cols>
class StaticMatrix{
private:
     size_t n_rows = Rows, n_cols = Cols;
     T data[Rows * Cols];
public:
     StaticMatrix() {}
     // ...
};
```

*How can I check for the Derived class type in `MatrixBase::some_function(const Derived &other)` to use this base function in both derived classes?*, preventing the need for redefinition/override/code duplicates in these classes separately. In this case it is basically only the declaration of the `result` matrix that requires me to check for the Derived class type, as the declaration is different depending on if its a fixed-size or dynamic matrix. Other solutions than type-checking are also welcome.

**NOTE**: I cannot use standard functionality due to the nature of my application.

**EDIT**: The `some_number_of_rows` and `some_number_of_cols` in the example function are in general not constexpr, as they are dependent on the function and size of the object matrix. For instance for a `transpose` function, the result would have to have dimension `<Derived.n_cols, Derived.n_rows`, and in the case of a column-wise dot product, `<1, Derived.n_cols>`.

Comment: Where do the `some_number_of_rows` and `some_number_of_cols` come from? From the `&other`?

Comment: *"Some calculations..., which will determine [..] `some_number_of_rows` and `some_number_of_cols`"*. These should be `constexpr` for `StaticMatrix`, how about `DynamicMatrix` ?

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

This is a challenging problem. Basically, `some_number_of_rows` and `some_number_of_cols` *must* be `constexpr` in case of `StaticMatrix`, and *cannot* be `constexpr` in case of `DynamicMatrix`.

One solution is to delegate new matrix creation to the derived class. It will do the size computation as `constexpr` or not `constexpr`, whichever works for it.

Another one is to make the size computation in the CRTP class twice, once as `constexpr` and once as not `constexpr`, and pass both results to the derived object creation function: `constexpr` is passed as a template argument, and non-`constexpr` as a regular argument. The creation function is specialized for both static and dynamic matrices. The static version ignores the non-`constexpr` parameters, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you might add those factory method inside `Derived`:

If `some_number_of_rows`, `some_number_of_cols` can be constexpr (to satisfy the more constrained `Derived`) in both case, you might do something like:

```
template<class T>
class DynamicMatrix
{
  // ...
  template <std::size_t Row, std::size_t Col>
  static DynamicMatrix<T> Create() { return DynamicMatrix(Row, Col); }
};

template <class T, int Rows, int Cols>
class StaticMatrix{
  // ...
  template <std::size_t Row, std::size_t Col>
  static StaticMatrix<T, Row, Col> Create() { return {}; }
};
```

With

```
auto result = Derived::Create<some_number_of_rows, some_number_of_cols>();
```

else you have to move that computation into Derived functions too:

```
template<class T>
class DynamicMatrix
{
  // ...
  DynamicMatrix<T> CreateEmptyTransposed() const { return DynamicMatrix(n_cols, n_rows); }
};

template <class T, int Rows, int Cols>
class StaticMatrix{
  // ...
  StaticMatrix<T, Cols, Row> CreateEmptyTransposed() const { return {}; }
};
```

With

```
auto result = self.CreateEmptyTransposed();
```

Comment: `Derived::Create<some_number_of_rows, some_number_of_cols>();` would be invalid in case of dynamic matrix, because the dimensions are not `constexpr` (and the fact that they are ignored inside doesn't make it legal).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: I placed an "if" in my explanation, as it is unclear if `some_number_of_rows`, `some_number_of_cols` are constexpr or not. And also provide "solution" in case there are not (with transposed example).

Comment: they are constexpr for static matrix and not constexpr for dynamic matrix (obviously).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: OP might want to create squared matrix with `sizeof T` ;) It is indeed more probable that it depends on dimension of Derived. I would hope my wording was clear enough :/